# How to create basic "fog of war" effect in Actionscript 3?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Hey all.  I'm working on a little flash game, that is a top down game.  Your character is placed in a 600x800 pixel area, and you can use the arrow keys to walk around (in 8 directions).  The object of the game is to avoid getting eaten by the enemy.

To make the game more interesting, I want to create a "fog of war" effect, so you can't see the entire map, but rather, only a small area around your character.  I'm thinking of keeping things very basic, what I'm looking for is the entire map to be blacked out, but a "circle of visibility" around your character.  Like this:

[image]

Of course, as the player moves around the map, the circle of visibility would move with him.  If there were obstacles, they would come "into view" as the player moved toward them.

I am not sure where to begin on implementing this feature.  I'm using actionscript 3 and would really appreciate your help on giving me ideas on how to implement it!  Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking to apply a "mask" to your visual.  You then need to update the properties of that mask at runtime as your character moves around.  Should be pretty straight forward.

See [this tutorial](http://insideria.com/2008/01/flex-graphics-tricks-part-1-ma.html) on masks for more.

**EDIT**
I realized I gave you a Flex example of using masks.  It seems you are are trying to do this with Flash.  The concept still applies... you want a mask.  See [this example](http://www.webwasp.co.uk/tutorials/006/index.php) or something similar for doing it in Flash.

Comment: Yes, this looks promising.  I'll start working on some code and let you know how it goes!  Thank you!